# Looping over two arrays of object to loop for matching ids. Then return a new array of custom objects based of custom values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

Hello I am still working on my JS skills and I am having trouble wrapping my head around this issue. I have two arrays, one of phone contacts and another of messages. I am trying to loop over each one and return a custom array with a new object based off the contacts array.

```
const myNumber = '69';

const contacts = [
    { 
      phoneNumber: '420',
      name: "Mike Smith",
      favorite: false,
      color: "orange"     
    },
    { 
      phoneNumber: '360',
      name: "John Smith",
      favorite: true,
      color: "green"     
    },
];

const messages = [
  // ! from john to me 
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '360',
      isRead: false,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 0,
      message: 'Hello there friend this is walker'
    },
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '360',
      isRead: true,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 1,
      message: 'Hello there friend this is walker'
    },
    // ! from random number to me 
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '720',
      isRead: false,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 0,
      message: 'Hello there friend from random person'
    },
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '720',
      isRead: true,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 1,
      message: 'Hello there friend from random person'
    }
];
```

I would like to return a new messages array that looks like this...

```
const newMessages = [
  // ! from John to me 
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '360',
      isRead: false,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 0,
      message: 'Hello there friend this is John',
      displayName: "John Smith"
    },
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '360',
      isRead: true,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 1,
      message: 'Hello there friend this is John',
      displayName: "John Smith"
    },
    // ! from random number to me 
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '720',
      isRead: false,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 0,
      message: 'Hello there friend from random person',
      displayName: '720',
    },
    {
      to: '69',
      from: '720',
      isRead: true,
      time: new Date(),
      owner: 1,
      message: 'Hello there friend from random person',
      displayName: '720',
    }
];
```

We add the display name property to the new messages objects. Display name will return contact name if either the "to" | "from" value == the contact "phoneNumber". If this is not the case the display name by default will return the message "from" value.

I really am not sure how to go about doing this. I tried looking at some other threads but I am having no luck. Please let me know if you have any advice. Also if this explanation was not helpful please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You must make an attempt of solving your own problem before asking for help. It would also help if you gave us examples of the threads you looked at and why they did not help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the item in `contacts` whose `phoneNumber` property is either the current item's `to` or `from` property. If an item is found, assign the item's `name` property to the current item's `displayName` property:

To implement a default display name, we can remove the `if` statement and use a ternary operator to assign the `name` property if an item was found, and otherwise assign the default display name.

```js
const myNumber = '69';

const contacts=[{phoneNumber:"420",name:"Mike Smith",favorite:!1,color:"orange"},{phoneNumber:"360",name:"John Smith",favorite:!0,color:"green"}];

const messages=[{to:"69",from:"360",isRead:!1,time:new Date,owner:0,message:"Hello there friend this is walker"},{to:"69",from:"360",isRead:!0,time:new Date,owner:1,message:"Hello there friend this is walker"},{to:"69",from:"720",isRead:!1,time:new Date,owner:0,message:"Hello there friend from random person"},{to:"69",from:"720",isRead:!0,time:new Date,owner:1,message:"Hello there friend from random person"}];

let defaultDisplayName = 'Spectric'

const result = messages.map(e => {
  let found = contacts.find(f => [e.to, e.from].includes(f.phoneNumber))
  e.displayName = found ? found.name : defaultDisplayName;
  return e;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works well but is there a way to add a default display name value of 'from', and if "let found" returns true use the contact display name instead? Thank you for the very fast response. I appreciate you! Also would doing that over complicate things?

Comment: @Zoot_00 I've updated my answer to have a default display name.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to do that for me! I am having a tough time wrapping my head around some of the higher order array function.

Comment: @Zoot_00 No problem. Which ones are you confused about?

Comment: map() really has me confused...

Comment: @Zoot_00 `map()` basically loops through the array and sets each item's value to the value returned by the callback, creating a new array in the process.

Comment: Thanks you @Spectric